# Rust macro not expanding recursively

Tags: rust, macros

I'm trying to write a macro that writes a function for me. Keep in mind that i have removed a lot of irrelevant details so i it may look a bit pointless.
My macro looks like so:

```rust
macro_rules! command {
    // Vars
    (@vars, $var: ident: ?$type: ty, $($t:tt)*) => {
        $var: Option<&$type>, command!(@vars, $($t)*)
    };
    (@vars, $var: ident: $type: ty, $($t:tt)*) => {
        $var: &$type, command!(@vars, $($t)*)
    };
    (@vars, ) => {};
    // Main
    ($name: ident ($($t:tt)*) $body: block) => {
        fn $name(command!(@vars, $($t)*)) $body
    };
}
```

And i invoke it like so:

```rust
command!(lol1_command(text: String, t: ?String,) {
    println!("test")
});
```

This gives me an error. When i expand it using rust analyzer i get this which works

```rust
fn lol1_command(text: &String, t: Option<&String>) {
    println!("cool");
}
```

The compile error i get is  `error: expected one of ':' or '|', found ')'`
and it recommends me `fn $name(_: command!(@ vars, text : String, t : ? String,)) $body`
which to me looks like it does not expand `command` recursively and insted thinks that the macro invokation is a parameter to the funktion. What is going on? I a'm quite confused. Thank in advance.

I have tried moving things around in the macro to try to move the function generation after the call the vars macro but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [reference of declarative macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html) says:

> Macros can expand to expressions, statements, items (including traits, impls, and foreign items), types, or patterns

Note that this list does *not* contain partial items such as a list of parameters, you can't produce that from a macro.

Instead of producing parts of the final function item you can pass those parts along and create a single, complete function item at the very end:

```rust
macro_rules! command {
    // Vars
    (
        $name:ident,
        $body:block,
        @vars ($var:ident : ? $type:ty , $($v:tt)*)
        @processed ($($p:tt)*)
    ) => {
        command!{
            $name,
            $body,
            @vars ($($v)*)
            @processed ($($p)*, $var: Option<&$type>)
        }
    };
    (
        $name:ident,
        $body:block,
        @vars ($var:ident : $type:ty , $($v:tt)*)
        @processed ($($p:tt)*)
    ) => {
        command!{
            $name,
            $body,
            @vars ($($v)*)
            @processed ($($p)*, $var: &$type)
        }
    };
    (
        $name:ident,
        $body:block,
        @vars ()
        @processed (,$($p:tt)*)
    ) => {
        fn $name($($p)*) $body
    };
    // Main
    ($name:ident ($($t:tt)*) $body: block) => {
        command!{$name, $body, @vars ($($t)*) @processed ()}
    };
}
```

Comment: Note: this pattern is called [push-down accumulation](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/decl-macros/patterns/push-down-acc.html)